# Defining custom map comparator with non stardard signature

Tags: c++, c++11

Assuming that there is a map that has a pointer as a key. To deep compare of the underling object it's possible to write custom comparator in following way:

```
#include <map>
#include <memory>

bool compare(std::unique_ptr<int> lhs, std::unique_ptr<int> rhs){
    return *lhs<*rhs;
}

int main(){
    std::map<std::unique_ptr<int>, short, bool (*)(std::unique_ptr<int>, std::unique_ptr<int>)> elements(compare);
}
```

That's undestandable, but why would I need to explicitly pass type of the compare callback as it is imposed by the type of map key? Why it's not possible create a map in following way as the signature of it should be known:

```
std::map<std::unique_ptr<int>, short> elements(compare);
```

Are there any cases when it's needed to define a compare function with different signature?

EDIT:

The last question I think I already answered to myself. At some point I could write something like:

```
#include <map>
#include <memory>

bool compare(std::unique_ptr<BaseClass> lhs, std::unique_ptr<BaseClass> rhs){
    return *lhs<*rhs;
}

int main(){
    std::map<std::unique_ptr<DerivedClass>, short, bool (*)(std::unique_ptr<BaseClass>, std::unique_ptr<BaseClass>)> elements(compare);
}
```

But it does not explain why by default exact signature is not used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why it's not possible create a map in following way as the signature of it should be known

But it's not known uniquely. The function is a valid initializer for at least two types of maps

```
std::map<std::unique_ptr<int>, short, bool (*)(std::unique_ptr<int>, std::unique_ptr<int>)>
std::map<std::unique_ptr<int>, short, bool (&)(std::unique_ptr<int>, std::unique_ptr<int>)>
```

A pointer or a reference to a function works equally well here. Neither is inherently better, so how's the type to be determined uniquely? There's no immediately compelling reason to favor one over the other.

It's also worth mentioning that the slightly more idiomatic use of a `std::map` is backwards. I.e. instead of figuring out the type from a comparator object, a user-defined type that can initialize objects is used instead. For example:

```
struct compare {
    bool operator()(std::unique_ptr<int> lhs, std::unique_ptr<int> rhs){
        return *lhs<*rhs;
    }
};

std::map<std::unique_ptr<int>, short, compare> elements;
```

Answer (score 1):

The type of the comparator is not at all determined by the type of the key. The comparator doesn't have to be a function, it could be a class overloading `operator()`.

In fact, the third template parameter has a default argument that is an instantiation of just such a class, namely `std::less<Key>`.  That is, `std::map<std::unique_ptr<int>, short>` is a shorthand for `std::map<std::unique_ptr<int>, short, std::less<std::unique_ptr<int>>>`